# How to use the sigmoid function to compute pixel's contrast

Tags: math, image-processing

I found out about how to increase or decrease a pixel's contrast, and my teacher answered me I could use this formula : `R = r*coefficient ; G = g*coefficient ; B = b*coefficient` where `R, G and B` are the contrasted pixel, and `r, g, b` its old values. The `coefficient` is a positive or negative percentage choosed by the final-user of my retouching program.

But this formula doesn't work. I searched on the Internet why and I found I must change this formula using for example **the sigmoid function**.

**So my question is :** is the formula I wrote below correct ? I don't think so because I did some tests : it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

`R = 1/(1 + Math.exp(-(r + coefficient*r)))`

NB : it would be fine if I could restrain the images of my function to : [0-255] and the abscissas to [0 - 255] but I don't know how.

Comment: I found this formuala, which makes use of sigmoid too and looks like mine : http://ccis2k.org/iajit/PDF/vol.1,no.2/10-nagla.pdf (page 2, right column). It doesn't work neither.

Comment: Start by explaining what doesn't work. Both methods should work if applied correctly. In the first case, the coefficient is a factor rather than a percentage of change (i.e. negative values do not really make sense). Usually, you probably want to scale with respect to a medium gray, i.e. `R = 128 + coefficient * (r - 128)`. If the coefficient is 2, you double the contrast. If it is 0.5, you halve it.

Comment: Are sou speaking about the method which doesn't use Sigmoid ? I don't understand why you used 128, the medium gray).

Comment: Yes, that's the method I meant. You can ignore the medium gray if you want. But then, you would also change the average brightness of the image because you scale with respect to 0 (black).

Comment: Mmmh I used your formula to increase the contrast by coef=2 of this image : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/306046Capture.png and I should have : http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/398460Capture2.png but instead, the image becomes entirely white. I don't understand why. =/

Comment: Show some code. The formula assumes that 128 is medium gray. Some libraries use float colors in the range [0, 1], where a medium gray would be 0.5.

Comment: I use JavaFX `double red = 0.5 + coefficient*(r - 0.5); red = (red > 1) ? 1 : red; red = (red < 0) ? 0 : red;`

Comment: A bit of context would help... But edit your question and don't use the comments for code. The formulas are correct. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: In fact it works fine... But I still don't understand why I must use the medium gray in the formula ? And why it can works without ? I begin in photo retouching.